# How to add Proxy Capability for Create Webdriver in RobotFramework

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am using ROBOT framework and need to create a webdriver with proxy capabilities to access a website sharklasers.com in headless  mode which has firewall to access in CMD or in headless mode, but its not working, I tried with various options..but its not working.
Note:I could find some options in Java, but not in robot Framework

I tried with  --proxy-server, http_proxy argument..both are not working

```
${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver

log    ${options}    
Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    headless
Call Method    ${options}    add_experimental_option      useAutomationExtension    ${FALSE}
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    headless
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    disable-gpu
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --proxy-server=bcppx-el01-int.uhc.com:8080

Create Webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=${CURDIR}/../../Drivers/chromedriver.exe    chrome_options=${options}
```

$I tried below Code also which is not working

```
${args}=    Create List    --proxy-server=bcprx-elr01-int.uhc.com:8080
${chrome_proxyoptions}=    Create Dictionary    args=${args} 
Create WebDriver    Chrome    executable_path=${CURDIR}/../../Drivers/chromedriver.exe    chrome_options= ${chrome_proxyoptions}
```

Expected:Browser should Open
Actual Result for code block1 :

```
20191021 21:35:30.389 : INFO : ${options} = <selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options object at 0x0000000017B0A240>
20191021 21:35:30.404 : FAIL : Calling method 'add_argument' failed: TypeError: add_argument() got an unexpected keyword argument '--proxy-server'
```

Actual Result for code block2:

```
20191021 21:39:26.073 : INFO : Sharktest
20191021 21:39:26.077 : INFO : ${args} = [u'--proxy-server=bcprx-elr01-int.uhc.com:8080']
20191021 21:39:26.079 : INFO : ${chrome_proxyoptions} = {u'args': [u'--proxy-server=bcprx-elr01-int.uhc.com:8080']}
20191021 21:39:26.082 : INFO : Creating an instance of the Chrome WebDriver.
20191021 21:39:26.084 : INFO : Cannot capture screenshot because no browser is open.
20191021 21:39:26.089 : FAIL : AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'
```